# rael time counter for many selects

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a dynamic list of products, and I need to know the total amount products selected by the users, for example 4 of product1, 5 of product5 and 6 of product9, so the value of the counter must be 15 (the adition of each product selected)

```
<select name="product1" id="product1" class="list-of-products">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
</select>
```

...
x products generated dynamically by php call
...

```
<select name="productx" id="productx" class="list-of-products">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
 </select>
```

so my counter is like

```
 <div id="counter">
   <span id="counter-value">counter</span>
 </div>
```

I've been thinking to do it using jquery,something like

```js
$(document).ready(
  function() {

    var total = 0;
    $('.list-of-products :selected').each(function(i, selected){
      total= total+ parseInt($(selected).text());
    });

    $('#counter-value').text(total);
  }
);
```

Comment: So add an onchange event and call your function.

Answer (score 0):

You're near the solution. Just check my fiddle:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.list-of-products').change(function () {
       var products = $('.list-of-products :selected');
       var tot = calculateTotal(products);
       $('#counter-value').text(tot);
    });
});

// Function
function calculateTotal(product_list) {
    var total = 0;
    product_list.each(function (i, selected) {
        total = total + parseFloat($(selected).text());
    });

    return total;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hoja/3pznw838/